# How To Use Userinput To Create A Set Number Of New Variables

Tags: java

I am trying to let the user input a number and then a loop will create the specified number of new variables.

I have tried declaring variables by appending a counter to the variable name like this:

```
String Var1(Counter); 
String Var1+Counter;
String Var1+(Counter);
String (Var+Counter);
```

And other combinations like that.  My full code is below:

```
System.out.print("How Many Variables Do You Want ");

Scanner Scan = new Scanner(System.in);
UserInput = Scan.nextInt();

while (Counter < UserInput){
    Counter++;  
    String Var(Counter) = "test";
    System.out.println(Var(Counter));
}
```

I expect `String Var(Counter) = "test";` to output as `String Var1 = "test";` and then increment the counter up to the user `int` input.  So the final variable created would be `String Var5 = "test"` if the user inputted a `5`.

All my error says is it expected `;` not a statement for the `Var(Counter)`.

My question is: How do I append a counter to a variable name?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your code doesn't make any sense. Please upload a code that can compile, so it's readable and therefore making it possible for us to help

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want the concept of an "array".  Something like:

```
String[] names;
names = new String[5];
names[3] = "Josh";

System.out.println( "The 4th name, at index 3, is " + names[3] );
```

Any basic programming text will have more about arrays, and using a loop to process every single index.

Comment: the issue with making a new array is that I need to be able to make a specified number of new arrays but I didn't add that in my code because its a giant code

Comment: @JoshVisentin not sure what you mean by "make a specified number of new arrays"; if you mean "be able to process a user-specified number of *`String`s*, then just replace the `5` with a number provided by the user (e.g. read a number from the input and store it in a variable `n`, and then say `… new String[n]`).

Answer (score 0):

I think I get what you’re trying to do - which is define an unknown number of variables in runtime with names that depend on the user input. I’m afraid that’s not possible.

However, I think that an array is something else that fits your situation almost perfectly. An array allows you to store n items of a certain type, where n can depend on run time.

For example, you could try something like:

```
String[] Var1 = new String[UserInput];
```

I recommend that you learn more about arrays [here](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_arrays.asp).

Comment: the issue with making a new array is that I need to be able to make a specified number of new arrays but I didn't add that in my code because its a giant code

Comment: If you need a “specified number of new arrays”, perhaps you want a matrix or ArrayList of arrays?